# How would you collect the first few entries of a list from a large json file using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to process a large json file for testing purposes that has a few thousand entries. The json contains a long list of `data` to is too large for me to process in one go. Using a jq, is there an easy way to get a valid snippet of the json that only contains the first few entries from the `data` list? For example is there a query that would look at the whole json file and return to me a valid json that only contains the first 4 entries from `data`? Thank you!

```
{
"info":{
"name":"some-name"
},
"data":[
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [streaming mode](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) initiated by the `--stream` [option](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq). It gives you a list of "parts" of the input JSON, which you can iterate over (and disregard items or even abort the process as you see fit). This way, only the portions you are interested in have to fit into the memory, not the whole input.

Comment: I am still novice in jq, but I am more looking for a programatic way to do via the CLI such as ```cat output.json | jq '. (some expression)' ```  to results in a useful snippet of the original json. Not sure though how hard that is though/if its possible

Comment: That's exactly how you would do it. For example: `jq --stream -n 'reduce inputs as … (…; …)' input.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your snippet, the relevant jq would be:

```
.data |= .[:4]
```

Comment: Thank you, this simple solution worked for my use case!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the `--stream` option:

```sh
$ cat input.json
{
  "info": {"name": "some-name"},
  "data": [
    {"a":1},
    {"b":2},
    {"c":3},
    {"d":4},
    {"e":5},
    {"f":6},
    {"g":7}
  ]
}
```

```sh
jq --stream -n '
  reduce (
    inputs | select(has(1) and (.[0] | .[0] == "data" and .[1] < 4))
  ) as $in (
    {}; .[$in[0][-1]] = $in[1]
  )
' input.json
```

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4
}
```

Note: Using `limit` would have been more efficient in this case, but I tried to be more generic for the purpose of scalability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is certainly a more generic way to do it, but for my simple use case, @peak's solution is more clear and direct.

Comment: @Jengels Your description of "a large json file […] that has a few thousand entries […] contains a long list of data to is too large for me to process in one go" made me think bigger :)